# postgresql join confusion

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make this statement work. but I can't figure it out.

> 4. List the names of the students who never took the course Databases.

I have this:

```
select distinct s1.name, e1.section_id
from students s1
    inner join enrollment e1 on e1.student_id = s1.id
where e1.course_id != 12
```

but that doesn't remove the student who took that section, so I'm stuck.

Database looks like (I'm soo sorry, I don't know how to insert the database into here)

```
table students (
    id              integer primary key,
    name            varchar(255),
    graduation_date date,
    major_id        integer references departments(id)
);

insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (1, 'Joe', null, 10);
insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (2, 'Amy', '2009-04-22', 20);
insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (3, 'Max', null, 10);


create table courses (
    id              integer primary key,
    title           varchar(255),
    units           integer,
    department_id   integer references departments(id)
);

insert into courses (id, title, units, department_id) values
    (12, 'Databases', 4, 10);
insert into courses (id, title, units, department_id) values
    (22, 'Compilers', 4, 10);
insert into courses (id, title, units, department_id) values
    (32, 'Calculus 1', 4, 20);

create table sections (
    id              integer primary key,
    course_id       integer not null references courses(id),
    instructor_id   integer references faculty(id),
    year            integer
);

insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (12, 12, 6, 2007);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (13, 12, 1, 2008);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (14, 22, 1, 2008);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (23, 12, 6, 2009);

create table enrollment (
    id          integer primary key,
    student_id  integer not null references students(id),
    section_id  integer not null references sections(id),
    grade_id    integer references grades(id)
);

insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (14, 1, 12, 8);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (15, 1, 13, 3);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (16, 1, 14, 5);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (17, 1, 32, 1);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (18, 1, 34, 2);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (19, 1, 53, 13);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (24, 3, 12, 2);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (25, 3, 14, 5);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (26, 3, 32, 1);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (27, 3, 34, 2);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (28, 3, 54, 7);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (34, 2, 43, 3);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what is the question here. You want us to just  write the query for you?

Comment: @JakubKania id like to know how to do the query , im kinda stuck on what to do. my iea was to join students,enrollement, and courses to do this , but i cant get it to work.

Comment: Easy way, do a NOT EXISTS. (Or GROUP BY with HAVING.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't join everything and then try to clean up with `DISTINCT`. That's a bad approach. Instead think of what you want to select first. Then write the query step by step.

The "students who never took the course Databases" are

- all students **except** those who took the course Databases
- all students who are **not in** the set of students who took the course Databases
- all students for whom **not exists** a Databases course enrolement

I have highlighted the keywords needed. So you have three options:

- Write a query with `EXCEPT`
- Write a query with `NOT IN`
- Write a query with `NOT EXISTS`

Try these and come back here if you have further problems.

**UPDATE:** Now that you solved it (and even accepted my answer :-), here are some ways to write the query:

Query with IN clause:

```
select name 
from students 
where id not in 
(
  select student_id 
  from enrollment 
  where section_id in 
  (
    select id 
    from sections 
    where course_id = (select id from courses where title = 'Databases')
  )
);
```

Query with EXISTS clause:

```
select name 
from students 
where not exists
(
  select * 
  from enrollment 
  where section_id in 
  (
    select id 
    from sections 
    where course_id = (select id from courses where title = 'Databases')
  )
  and student_id = students.id
);
```

Query with EXCEPT (which is not so good a solution here, because it queries the students table twice, but sometimes EXCEPT is the straight-forward way to a problem). I am using a join on a subquery here instead of `WHERE students.id IN (...)`, just in order to show the technique.

```
select name 
from students 
join
(
  select id
  from students
  except
  select student_id 
  from enrollment 
  where section_id in 
  (
    select id 
    from sections 
    where course_id = (select id from courses where title = 'Databases')
  )
) found_students on found_students.id = students.id;
```

Query with COUNT and HAVING, which looks quite compact. It is however a bit more prone to errors. One thing is not to confuse ON and WHERE in outer joins, another is to count the correct column. We must make sure to count a non-nullable field of table sections, so we are sure none of the student's enrollments matched an actual Databases section.

```
select s.id, s.name
from students s
left join enrollment e on e.student_id = s.id
left join sections s on s.id = e.section_id 
                     and s.course_id = (select id from courses where title = 'Databases')
group by s.id, s.name
having count(s.id) = 0;
```

Comment: What about `LEFT JOIN`? It seems like the most simple aproach to the problem.

Comment: @Jakub Kania: An outer join? There would be two options: 1. join, group and count. But beginners often make mistakes with aggregations combined with outer joins. It is a good enough approach, but not what you would do when only starting to learn SQL. 2. Do an anti-join. But this is a special trick used on DBMS that still have issues with IN and EXISTS clauses and is certainly nothing I would recommend to a beginner.

Comment: well so far i have this , select distinct s1.name, e1.section_id from students s1 
left join enrollment e1 on e1.student_id = s1.id where e1.section_id =12  which gives me the names of the students that are taking Databases.

Comment: @henryzo: Why do you outer join the enrollment table? That makes no sense in your query (and doesn't work anyhow, because in your `WHERE` clause, you dismiss any outer-joined records). ` = 12` must be replaced by an `IN` clause `in (select course_id from sections ...)`. And at last you join students with the student IDs found in Databases enrollments, whereas you would like to join with the student IDs not found therein (e.g. select "all Student IDs" `EXCEPT` select "student IDs found in Databases enrollments") . Do you know how to join a subquery, already?

Comment: But  `NOT IN` is easier: `select * from students where id not in (...)`

Comment: weve learned about them but havent used a subquery yet. lol god this feels like its impossible to do. i feel like im trying to join to many tables and im over thinking it. i know student has to to go through enrollment to get so you can see what students took what classes. but then im thinking i have to join the secton an coures tables as well. which i dont think is right lol

Comment: oh man , i think i made progress lol .is this right?   select name from students where id NOT IN (select student_id from enrollment where section_id =12)  it looks right , but i dont know if having the id= 12 is good to have there? i thought that i should somehow join it to the course table to get the name of the course instead, or is it fine to jut use an ID like that

Comment: Yes, that is correct so far. Now repace that `section_id =12`, because in your query you should *find out* what sections represent the Databases course.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner im pretty lost at trying to replace that section_id=12.  i was trying to do 3 sub querys but it snot coming out right. tried doin this ,,, select name from students where id NOT IN (select id from enrollment where section_id in 
(select id from sections where course_id in
(select id from courses where title='Databases')))   but it keeps giving me all the students

Comment: Looks fine, except you suddenly select **id** from enrollment instead of **student_id**, which is certainly the reason for not getting the correct result :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thank you very much for the help , now i gotta study what i just did so i can understand it clearer lol.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Anti join is not really that complicated, and I believe you made the example with aggregation too complicated. I added a more simplistic version in my own answer.

Comment: @Jakub Kania: No an anti-join is not very complicated, but why use it at all when you can use a straight-forward `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`? I don't teach tricks, before the basics are understood. Once you are in the rare situation to work with a weak DBMS having problems in dealing with EXISTS and IN (like early versions of MySQL), you can still look up how to go about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the queries above over complicate the topic a bit so I added my own.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM students s
   LEFT JOIN (enrollment e
       INNER JOIN sections se
         ON se.id = e.section_id
       INNER JOIN courses c
         ON c.id = se.course_id AND c.title = 'Databases')
     ON s.id = e.student_id
WHERE
  e.id IS NULL
```

Comment: As mentioned, outer joins and tricks are always prone to errors. Your query doesn't work. You'd have to outer join sections and courses and check **c**.id for null for the anti join to work. Something a beginner would have difficulties to find out. Better use a straight-forward way to write the query that will be easier to correct in case of wrong results.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The outer join is deferred, apart from using the same alias for two tables (fixed) the code does work and returns a correct result. Please notice we inner join the three tables and then left join to the result of those inner joins.

Comment: I am sorry. My statement above is wrong. Your query is correct. I had simply never seen a deferred join before and missed the ON clause not directly following `LEFT JOIN enrollment e`. I would have even thought this to be syntactically incorrect, had your query not worked. So I read up on that syntax and learned something new. Thank you.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's cool, and I know it's easy to miss, probably should've added the parantheses.

Comment: For anybody else who wants to see this query working, here is the SQL fiddle I used: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4388b/1

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i had one more question if you dont mind on a similar query, im trying to  List the names of the students who took both Databases and Compilers.  isnt this the same query just with an and for the compiler title? i came up with this , which i think works. but im not sure...select name from students where id in
(select student_id from enrollment where section_id in 
(select id from sections where course_id in 
(select id from courses where title='Databases' and title='Compilers')));